# How do I prevent YouTube from showing "static" (noisy) background when video is not available?

Tags: youtube

I visit YouTube with scripts or video tag turned off, so YouTube cannot play video. I just want to read comments, description and so on, but YouTube shows noisy animated background that slows down (tricky and unaccelerated) video output.

[image: Youtube error page with static background]

How do I turn off animated YouTube error page?